# Scrapy - Ubuntu - Error when calling the metaclass bases

Tags: python, scrapy

Making some progress now! problem is that I cannot extract the price from the site can you guys tell me what is wrong with the price field?

```
import scrapy
class MilSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'mil'
allowed_domains = ['milsims.com.au']
start_urls = ['http://www.milsims.com.au/catalog/1746'

]

def parse(self, response):
    for title in response.css('div.views-field-title'):
        yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

    for price in response.css('div.views-field-phpcode'):
        yield {'price': price.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

    next_page = response.css('li.pager-nexta::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Regards

Comment: Is that your real code? look at indentation of code, its completely messed up.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I am getting there, still learning! So now I was able to scrape the title of the games, however I still cannot get the price. Can you help me with that? What is wrong in the below please (let me try to add the new code)

Comment: Post your full perfectly idented code in your question

Comment: I have just updated my post with the Spider... this one is working for scraping the product titles but I still cannot scrape the prices :(

Comment: Your CSS Selector was incorrect, you are doing `div.views-field-phpcode` ... that is correct, but then you are doing `a::text` but there is no `a` tag inside `div.views-field-phpcode` ... Anyways, Please read my answer, that should work, if that works please upvote and mark my answer accepted ... My pro tip is that, always use `Firebug` or `Inspect Element` in Chrome to test your CSS or Xpath expression, then write into code.

Comment: May I just ask if you can kindly let me know how the YIELD line mjst looks like? I saw that you kindly helped below but now I need to properly write the yield to finish the code and I am not able to do it alone :(  . Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would approach, just think of a sulitoin in your mind and then translate into code, Iterate over each `TD` holding a product, and then grab the title and prices.

```
for product in resposne.css(".view-advanced-catalog tr > td"):

    item = {}

    item['name'] = product.css(".views-field-title").extract_first()

    item['old_price'] = product.css(".views-field-phpcode span span::text").extract()[0]
    item['new_price'] = product.css(".views-field-phpcode span span::text").extract()[1]
    yield item
```

Comment: May I just ask if you can kindly let me know how the YIELD line mjst looks like? I saw that you kindly helped below but now I need to properly write the yield to finish the code and I am not able to do it alone :(  . Thank you very much !

Comment: Just do yield item inside for loop

Comment: it worked :)  The only thing is that the extraction is now like this: "<span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">$69.95</span>" ... is there a way to get only the numbers instead of the whole text? Thanks you are the best !

Comment: Just one last question I promise. How do I extract the text from the button “add to cart” and the url for the pictures of each product? Thanks!